# How do you use an Nullable<T> parameter with an nHibernate Linq Expression?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am consistently running into the following error

> PartialEvalException (InvalidOperationException ("Nullable object must have a value."), Convert(PartialEvalException (InvalidOperationException ("Nullable object must have a value."), PartialEvalException (InvalidOperationException ("Nullable object must have a value."), Convert(PartialEvalException (InvalidOperationException ("Nullable object must have a value."), Convert(null)))).GetInvolvementType())))

when I attempt to run a nHibernate Linq query with the following where clause:

```
 where (Id.HasValue == false || (Id.HasValue && tbl.Id == Id.Value))
                    && (myDate.HasValue == false || (myDate.HasValue && tbl.Date <= myDate.Value))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate probably can't translate `HasValue` into a SQL statement properly, I would try comparing with `null`:

```
(Id == null || tbl.Id == Id) && (myDate == null || tbl.Date <= myDate))
```

Note that the check for `HasValue` in the second part of each `&&` clause is redundant--I've gone ahead and removed it. You should also be fine directly comparing non-nullable and nullable types this way.